# Is liquid metallic hydrogen, when used as a spacecraft fuel, a chemical fuel?

Tags: physics, spaceships, language

Is it scientifically sound to call liquid metallic hydrogen a chemical rocket fuel?

Comment: Advertiser's voice: "Welcome to our new *Hydrospand* it will revolutionize your experience of space travel." Care to constrain your question in such a way as a best answer can be identified?

Comment: What's wrong with plain "fuel"? We needed fuel. We refueled the ship. The fuel is in the tank. We have fuel for three more burns. We are running out of fuel. I've never ever heard anybody call gasoline, or kerosene, or fuel oil, or whatever anything other than fuel. I don't think I've ever heard the phrase "chemical fuel" spoken aloud.

Comment: Boomboom go fast juice sounds as good as any. Why are you looking for a name? What kind of reason do you think that things like fuel or your own LMH (ElemH?) isnt enough?

Comment: @AlexP you might not have _heard_ anyone distinguish different kinds of fuel, but you'll note that the people _selling_ it generally do, because no-one really wants to put petrol in a diesel engine, or vice versa.

Comment: @StarfishPrime: Of course. But then they use the actual name -- diesel, LPG, gasoline. Nobody uses fancy phrases such as "chemical fuel".

Comment: Just curious but Liquid and Metallic seem like 2 distinct states of hydrogen, is it a liquid medium containing metallic hydrogen?

Comment: Voting: - Off topic, not about worldbuilding. Could have been a vote to put it off topic as "unclear" also, but since you've not given us worldbuilding context...

Comment: Mind the difference between fuel and propellant.

Comment: @aCVn Well, they can be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question as it's asked - sure.  If you're burning it (rather than pouring it through a [nuclear thermal rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_thermal_rocket)), then it's inarguably a chemical rocket fuel.

As some of the commenters have pointed out, it's potentially a little hoity-toity for the tough, grizzled space adventurers using it - probably they'd call it LMH/fuel, and then shorten it further to "elem" or something.  But if the question being asked is what appears in the body of your question, then yes.  It's a chemical rocket fuel, because it generates thrust via a chemical reaction providing the energy to fling the fuel out the back of the rocket.